# Import data and rename sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple template sheet with a button to import.
The idea is that every time another workbook is "picked" the corresponding data form the sheet "summary" is imported into the activesheet with the button.
I, however wan't to rename the activesheet with a part of the filename from other workbook e.g. workbook to import Test_somthing.. then after importing the data "Test - Summary".

I know I am almost there but especially the renaming of the sheet is a problem.

```
Sub Import()
  Dim FileNames As Variant
    Dim FileName As Variant
    Dim WSNew1 As Worksheet
    Dim ActiveListWB As Workbook
    Set DestinationWB = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet


    FileNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*.xls*", _
                                               Title:="Select Foreto Import", _
                                               MultiSelect:=True)


    If VarType(FileNames) = vbBoolean Then
        If Not FileNames Then Exit Sub
    End If


    For Each FileName In FileNames

        Set WSNew1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        'I know this is adding the sheet not only copying the sheet data

        Set ActiveListWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
        ActiveListWB.Sheets("Summary").Range("D2:CI206").Copy
        DestinationWB.Range("A1:Z40").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

        WSNew1.Name = Split(ActiveListWB.Name, "_")(0) & " - Summary"
        'wan't to rename active in active workbook not import and rename a sheet        

        ActiveListWB.Close False
    Next FileName

End Sub
```